# Python writing list of dictionaries

Tags: python, file, dictionary

What's the best way to write a list of dictionaries to a file in python?

```
d1 = {"apple": 3}
d2 = {"banana": 1}
data = []
data.append(dict(d1))
data.append(dict(d2))  #data is now [{"apple": 3}, {"banana": 1}]
```

I want to write that list to a file and also read the list and eventually add another dictionaries
Something like:

```
f = open(..)
l = f.read()
```

and now `l` is a list of dictionaries that I can manipulate

Also adding dictionaries to the list like

```
d3 = {"orange": 1}
f.write(d3)
```

And now the file contains `[{"apple": 3}, {"banana": 1}, {"orange": 1}]`

Is this even possible? If so, what's the best approach?

Comment: If you want to store it in a plain text, you will need to write a parser for it. Or, you can use something like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store and retrieve objects like lists and dictionaries.

Comment: Are you familiar with json https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html ?

Comment: `ast_literal_eval` can parse a string containing such a list of dictionaries easily enough, though `json` is probably a more principled approach.

Comment: if i do l = json.load(f) i'll have the correct list?

Comment: @AndréClérigo Try and see! Python makes it very easy to just experiment to see if a method does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `json` module:

```py
>>> import json
>>> with open("sample.txt", "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```

And to read the file:

```py
>>> with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
        data = json.load(file)

>>> data
[{'apple': 3}, {'banana': 1}]
```

Comment: can you tell me why this isn't working? https://pastebin.com/G7qAYwpU the function is called the first time and the list is made exactly has I want it, but when I run it a second time the content from .txt is wipped

Comment: If you call `open()` with the `"w"` mode, the contents of the file will be deleted. If you want to append contents to the file, you would use the `"a"` mode.

Comment: If I use 'a' I get this erro message https://pastebin.com/G7qAYwpU

Comment: That would be because you are improperly using `json` (since it's an exception raised by `json`). If it's just plain text which you need to add, you can use the `"a"` mode. However, if you are trying to read and write with `json` with the `"a"` mode, then you will get errors. If you think about it, you would see that you are trying to read back-to-back lists with `json`, which does not work.